# как сделать hover эффекты как на примере

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[Тут в примере](http://www.os-templates.com/free-website-templates/kelaby) нажмите на жёлтую кнопку и откроется демо сайта, где-то по середине сайта есть 5 картинок, при наведении на которые они заполняются беым фоном, а текс становится черным. как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код страницы. Если появятся дополнительные вопросы — добавьте их в тело основного вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такой эффект можно достичь CSS свойством [transition](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition);

```css
.block {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```